# I have deployed my Tailwind CSS project on GitHub and it suddenly stopped working on pages deployment

Tags: user-interface, github, github-actions, tailwind-css, github-pages

When I ran it on my system in my local server it was working fine but when I deployed it on GitHub pages Deployment, GitHub doesn't seem to load my CSS and the CSS was not applied on my file.

repository link: https://github.com/pawangupta5050/Facebook-Login-Clone

live-website link on GitHub pages :https://pawangupta5050.github.io/Facebook-Login-Clone/

Comment: Please don't use links to repositories, but provide a minimal reproducing example. This will help people in the future with the same problem to find your question.

Comment: Please follow this to use tailwind in production https://dev.to/raphaelmansuy/how-to-add-tailwindcss-to-a-simple-html-project-446g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using this...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/index.76858414.css">
```

Instead of this...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.76858414.css">
```

> You can read more about **HTML file paths** [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).